# How to understand the sample from python minimock?

Tags: python, mocking

How to understand this line?

```
>>> smtplib.SMTP.mock_returns =  Mock('smtp_connection')?
```

What is smtp_connection? It 
seems I can modify it to any name.

### following is from minimock

```
Here's an example of something we might test, a simple email sender::                                                        

>>> import smtplib                                                                                                       
>>> def send_email(from_addr, to_addr, subject, body):                                                                   
...     conn = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')                                                                                 
...     msg = 'To: %s\nFrom: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s' % (                                                                  
...         to_addr, from_addr, subject, body)                                                                           
...     conn.sendmail(from_addr, [to_addr], msg)                                                                         
...     conn.quit()
```

Now we want to make a mock `smtplib.SMTP` object.  We'll have to
inject our mock into the `smtplib` module::

```
>>> smtplib.SMTP = Mock('smtplib.SMTP')                                                                                  
>>> smtplib.SMTP.mock_returns = Mock('smtp_connection')
```

Now we do the test::

```
>>> send_email('ianb@colorstudy.com', 'joe@example.com',                                                                 
...            'Hi there!', 'How is it going?')                                                                          
Called smtplib.SMTP('localhost')                                                                                         
Called smtp_connection.sendmail(                                                                                         
    'ianb@colorstudy.com',                                                                                               
    ['joe@example.com'],                                                                                                 
    'To: joe@example.com\nFrom: ianb@colorstudy.com\nSubject: Hi there!\n\nHow is it going?')                            
Called smtp_connection.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [rest of the docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MiniMock/1.0) you'll see the following:

> Mock objects have several attributes,
>   all of which you can set when
>   instantiating the object. To avoid
>   name collision, all the attributes
>   start with mock_, while the
>   constructor arguments don't.
>
> `name`:
>       The name of the object, used when printing out messages. In the example
>   about it was 'smtplib.SMTP'.

It's the name of the connection, used e.g. in:

```
Called smtp_connection.sendmail(                                                                                         
    'ianb@colorstudy.com',                                                                                               
    ['joe@example.com'],                                                                                                 
    'To: joe@example.com\nFrom: ianb@colorstudy.com\nSubject: Hi there!\n\nHow is it going?')                            
Called smtp_connection.quit()
```

Comment: What is the type of smtp_connection? really confused.

Comment: It's a string. Just a name for the test to use, so that you can identify it when mock methods are called. If you changed it to `spam`, the above code would contain e.g. `Called spam.sendmail( ... )`.